# should the model variance from variance for all folds or for all repeats in repeated-n-fold cross validation?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, caret

In 10-fold-5-repeat-CV, I have two ways to calculate the model variance. in the first one, I calculate the variance using accuracies of all 50 validation sets. In the second one, I first calculate an accuracy of merged test set results from all 10 folds from a single repeat, then I calculate the variance of accuracies of different repeats.

Given that my data may be sparse, if I'm interested to know the data performance and also how different training methods differ. Which accuracy variance calculation method should I use?